# JBoss JMS MDB is losing messages

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I have a pretty standard web app on EAP 7.2. Requests come in through a servlet which sends a message to a JMS queue which is then processed by an MDB. Maybe 50% of the time the `onMessage()` method on the MDB is never invoked when the producer sends the message. There are no errors in the server log file. Here's the basic setup:

jboss config:

```xml
<jms-queue name="HIFWebHookQueue" entries="HifWebHookQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/HifWebHookQueue"/>
```

Servlet side:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "/")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/HifWebHookQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        ObjectMessage msg = context.createObjectMessage(evt);  //evt is a serializable pojo
        producer.send(queue,evt);
    }
```

the MDB side:

```java
@MessageDriven(name = "WebhookListenerEJB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="messagingType", propertyValue="javax.jms.MessageListener"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="java:/jms/queue/HIFWebHookQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="ConnectionFactoryName", propertyValue="ConnectionFactory"),
})
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class WebhookListenerEJB implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
        ... stuff ...
        message.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Here's output from the JBoss CLI after sending 1st message (and no MDB event):

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=HIFWebHookQueue:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "consumer-count" => 30,
        "dead-letter-address" => "jms.queue.DLQ",
        "delivering-count" => 0,
        "durable" => true,
        "entries" => [
            "HifWebHookQueue",
            "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/HifWebHookQueue"
        ],
        "expiry-address" => "jms.queue.ExpiryQueue",
        "legacy-entries" => undefined,
        "message-count" => 0L,
        "messages-added" => 1L,
        "paused" => false,
        "queue-address" => "jms.queue.HIFWebHookQueue",
        "scheduled-count" => 0L,
        "selector" => undefined,
        "temporary" => false
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram.  thanks. I updated the question with queue stats.  I don't see an "acked message count" in the response.

Comment: It looks like the messaging subsystem on EAP doesn't expose the acked message count from the underlying instance of ActiveMQ Artemis. However, it does expose `messages-added` so we can infer from the data you provided that one of the 30 total consumers on `HifWebHookQueue` received the one message which was sent because `messages-added` is `1` and `message-count` (i.e. how many messages are currently on the queue waiting to be consumed) is `0`. If the MDB didn't receive a message I would expect to see  `message-count` _and_ `messages-added` _and_ `consumer-count` > 0.

Comment: In short, at this point I see no evidence of a problem.

Comment: @JustinBertram - I meant the  "onMessage()" handler. the MDB did not receive the message.

Comment: How do you know the MDB did not receive the message? According to the metrics you provided `HifWebHookQueue` has consumers and a message was added to the queue that is no longer there. _Something_ consumed that message. The default number of concurrent sessions for an MDB is 15 so I would expect your `consumer-count` to be 15. Since it is 30 then perhaps you have another MDB listening on the same queue. Have you explored this possibility?

Comment: There is no other MDB listening on the queue, and I have a breakpoint in the debugger in the MDB code, and 1/2 the time it never hits. I also update a table with the status, and it does not get updated.  Very strange.

Comment: The evidence indicates that there is another consumer on the queue given that `message-count` is 0 and `messages-added` is 1. How are you confirming there is no other consumer on the queue? Can you run `/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=HIFWebHookQueue:list-consumers-as-json`?

Comment: @JustinBertram - you were correct.  I am an idiot.  I had an earlier version of the code with a test MDB in a different package that I forgot about.  Please submit an answer so I can give you credit for the time you spent.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you provided indicates that one of the 30 total consumers on `HifWebHookQueue` received the one message which was sent because `messages-added` is 1 and `message-count` (i.e. how many messages are currently on the queue waiting to be consumed) is 0. If the message wasn't consumed I would expect to see `message-count` and `messages-added` and `consumer-count` > 0.
The default number of concurrent sessions for an MDB is 15 so I would expect your consumer-count to be 15. Since it is 30 then you almost certainly have another MDB deployed also consuming from `HifWebHookQueue`.

You can run the following command to see all the consumers for `HifWebHookQueue`:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=HIFWebHookQueue:list-consumers-as-json?
```